# Distributing a Visual flow to community user?

Tags: community, partner-communities

I have created a flow and i want to distribute it to Customer Community user. I know that i can embed the flow in a VF page and distribute it to the users but i have a limitation of not to use VF pages.

Do any one have any alternate approach of distributing the flow?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding in a Visualforce page is still the only option for distributing a flow to a community user, whether that is on Customer Community licence or any of the other types of licence available for community users.

[Visualforce to embed flow documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_external.htm)